# Name validation form not allowing an empty space between the names

Tags: php

i'm trying to not allow the users to introduce special caracters inside the name input box , but it also doesn't allow the user to leave an empty space between his first and last name.

I'm using a built it php function for the validation.

Does anyone know what should i add to it to allow empty spaces?

Here is the line.

```
 elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $name)) {
    $errorName = true;
}
```

Comment: Just add a space to your character class. If you want to enforce a single space, just repeat your character class with a space between them. Note that these restrictions are rarely a good idea. "John O'Connel" and "Luis Bruñel" would both fail your updated validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `^[a-zA-Z0-9]*( [a-zA-Z0-9]*)?$`

https://regex101.com/r/KIY77S/2

to allow a single space, or simply `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$` to allow any number of spaces